# Using ToList() method on IEnumerable<T> which is already a List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using the ToList() method on IEnumerable **which is already a List**:

1. Will it create a new List?
2. In performance manner: its complexity will still be O(n) or less?

Comment: If you use it on the list (`list = list.ToList()`) it simply makes no sense and does nothing. If you use it to create a new list (`var list2 = list1.ToList()`) it will create a copy of the list (as oposed to just a reference as `var list2 = list1` does). There will not be overhead.

Comment: `collection.ToList()`, unless the collection *type* has a method called `.ToList()` will always create a new list, even if the collection is a list to begin with. So it doesn't *do nothing*.

Answer (score 2):

1. It will create a new list.
2. It will copy over the elements internally using `Array.CopyTo` which is (from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copyto?view=net-5.0)) O(n)

you can see the code of the constructor of `list` (which is what is being called) [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,74)

Comment: It will use `ICollection.CopyTo`.

Comment: It calls `new List(list)` which in turn calls `list.CopyTo` which calls `Array.CopyTo`, and that is very fast. It may be `O(n)` but it's highly optimized

Answer (score 0):

It is simple yet some clarification required.

1. Yes. It will create new list instance.
2. Now when it comes to create new list. It will copy all items in it. If it is valuetype then actual value is being copy and if it is reference type then that ref is being copied.
   It is O(n).

   ```
     class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Value Type
            List<int> valueTypeitems = new List<int>();
            valueTypeitems.Add(1);
            valueTypeitems.Add(2);

            var newlist = valueTypeitems.ToList();
            valueTypeitems[0] = 3; // This will only reflect in first list.
            valueTypeitems.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc));
            newlist.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc));

            //Reference type
            List<Test> refItems = new List<Test>();
            refItems.Add(new Test() { Value = 1 });
            refItems.Add(new Test() { Value = 2 });

            var newrefList = refItems.ToList();
            refItems.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));
            newrefList.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));
            refItems[0].Value = 10; //This reflect in both list. As object is same but you change value.

            refItems.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));
            newrefList.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));

            //if you actually change ref in one list then it will not reflect
            refItems[0] = new Test() { Value = 30 };
            refItems.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));
            newrefList.ForEach(cc => Console.WriteLine(cc.Value));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class Test
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
        }
    }
   ```